# Carregar dinamicamente conteúdo da página

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Basicamente estou tentando criar uma função que ao receber uma variável de nome, procura pelo nome do jogador no site do jogo e retorna as informações desse jogador caso ele exista no registro do jogo. Para isso estou utilizando **puppeteer** para o web scrapping.

Resumindo, quero que o código, através do puppeteer, entre na página do jogo, insira o nome de usuário enviado pelo usuário na caixa de pesquisa, clique para pesquisar, atualize a lista de jogadores abaixo revelando se ela contém ou não o jogador, caso contenha, clique outra vez no link que vai mostrar para a página de perfil desse jogador, onde dela vou estar extraindo as informações como patente, exp, clã, etc...

O código que tenho até então é:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getProfile(Player){
    if(Player.toString().length > 12){
        console.log('O nome deve conter no máximo 12 caracteres!')
        return;
    }
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    })
    await page.goto('https://br.crossfire.z8games.com/playerranking.html');
    await page.evaluate((Player) => {
        document.querySelector('input#searchranks').value = Player;
    }, Player).then(async() => {
        await page.click('input#submitsearch');
    })
}
getProfile('teste');
```

Só não sei como posso fazer para retornar o conteúdo HTML da página atualizado após a função `page.click()`. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz e me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a busca é feita na mesma página você só precisa aguardar o carregamento do resultado

```
await page.waitFor(5000)
// espera por 5 segundos
```

e continuar o scraping da página :)

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    // ...
})
```

Edit: Há outros métodos [wait](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) também.. Além disso aconselho desenvolver com o puppeteer sem modo headless para você ver as ações na página com o chromium:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
```

Comment: Então, testei o que você disse e gostei da ideia do headless false, pois agora consigo ver o que o navegador faz. O problema parece estar no click, pois o elemento acende como se o mouse estivesse em cima, porém não efetua o clique